# Drawing a turtle histogram that corresponds with the amount of times a dice is rolled

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm fairly new to python so please bare with me. I'm trying to make a turtle histogram that counts the amount of times various numbers come up with 100 rolls of 3 dice. But after calculating the max height for my histogram with the total I got from the trials of my dice roll the histogram comes out completely different than I expected. My current histogram output and the expected histogram are attached below. #Note that the output keeps on changing because it has randrange Thanks in advance.

Current Code

```
from random import randrange
import turtle

totals = dict()
for i in range(3, 19):
    totals[i] = 0
    
# TODO: Set a variable called trials here so we can loop 100 times
trials = 100
for i in range(trials):
     first_roll = randrange(1, 7)
     second_roll = randrange(1, 7)
     third_roll = randrange(1, 7)
     total = first_roll + second_roll + third_roll
     print(total)
     totals[total] += 1


maxheight = 0
for i in range(3, 19):
    print(i, totals[i])
    if totals[i] > maxheight:
        maxheight = totals[i]
scr = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()

t.penup()
t.goto(-138, -175)
t.pendown()

for i in range(3, 19):
    t.write(i, align="center")
    t.forward(20)

t.penup()
t.goto(-150, -175)
t.pendown()

for i in range(3, 19):
    height = int(totals[i] * 300 / maxheight)
    t.forward(height)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(20)
    t.backward(height)
# TODO: In the end, draw the line at the bottom of our histogram

scr.exitonclick()
```

Current output
[image]

Expected output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this code:

```
for i in range(3, 19):
    height = int(totals[i] * 300 / maxheight)
    t.forward(height)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(20)
    t.backward(height)
```

It doesn't take into account the current orientation of the turtle nor leave the turtle in a reasonable orientation.  Consider instead:

```
for i in range(3, 19):
    height = int(totals[i] * 300 / maxheight)

    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.left(90)
```

Which assumes the turtle is facing 0 degrees when it starts and leaves the turtle facing 0 degrees.  Complete code with additional tweaks:

```
from random import randrange
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

TRIALS = 100
COLUMN_WIDTH = 20

totals = dict()

for i in range(3, 19):
    totals[i] = 0

for _ in range(TRIALS):
    first_roll = randrange(1, 7)
    second_roll = randrange(1, 7)
    third_roll = randrange(1, 7)
    total = first_roll + second_roll + third_roll
    totals[total] += 1

maxheight = 0

for i in range(3, 19):
    if totals[i] > maxheight:
        maxheight = totals[i]

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-160 - COLUMN_WIDTH/2, -175)
turtle.pendown()

turtle.forward(COLUMN_WIDTH)

for i in range(3, 19):
    turtle.write(i, align="center")
    turtle.forward(COLUMN_WIDTH)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-160, -175)
turtle.pendown()

for i in range(3, 19):
    height = int(totals[i] * 300 / maxheight)

    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(COLUMN_WIDTH)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.left(90)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]